# Get label text from tapped cell with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to edit label text on tap of the cell label (not `didSelectRowAt`). Tapped label function (`toDoItemLabelTapped`) shows nil.

Though `UITapGestureRecognizer` works well, it doesn't pass label text.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as!  ToDoItemsCell

    cell.delegate = self

    cell.textField.delegate = self
    cell.textField.isHidden = true
    cell.toDoItemLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let aSelector : Selector = Selector(("toDoItemLabelTapped"))
    var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector)

    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    tapGesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector)

    return cell
}
```

And here is the function:

```
var customTableViewController = ToDoItemsCell()

@objc func toDoItemLabelTapped() {
    print(customTableViewController.toDoItemLabel.text)
}
```

The error is the following:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

How to make the tap gesture pass the cell's label text?

Comment: Use the closure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your `customTableViewController` variable. It's referring to a useless cell that's not ever in the table view. Get rid of it. It's not necessary.

Get the cell from the tap gesture. A tap gesture has a `view` property. Since you add the tap gesture to the cell, its `view` property will be the cell.

```
@objc func toDoItemLabelTapped(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let cell = gesture.view as! ToDoItemsCell
    print(cell.toDoItemLabel.text)
}
```

You also need to fix the selector in `cellForRowAt`. Get rid of the `aSelector` variable.

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toDoItemLabelTapped))
```

Unless you have actually implement the gesture delegate methods for some reason, get rid of the line:

```
tapGesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

Also remove the extraneous line:

```
tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector)
```

Also note that cells are reused so you are adding more and more tap gestures to each cell as the user scrolls. You may want to avoid adding more than one tap gesture to any cell.

Comment: "You may want to avoid..." should read "You definitely should avoid..." adding a gr with the same target and action over and over.  Look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622542-gesturerecognizers to see how to test for that condition.

Comment: @danh Thanks for your comment! In my case, i need to apply removeGestureRecognizer,  but how can I do this to stop cells from reusing?

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks for your solution, it worked! Now i need to use `func textFieldShouldReturn(_ userText: UITextField) -> Bool` to stop editing textField. How can I define cell there?

Comment: Only change which was in my case was `let cell = gesture.view?.superview?.superview as? as! ToDoItemsCell`. Because gesture.view only gets you the current view it is holding, so in my case it was a UILabel inside the Content View.